# Perl hash: while-each-loop runs into endless loop

Tags: perl, loops, hash, each, infinite-loop

The following Perl code runs into an endless loop. 
It looks like `each` resets itself after the subroutine call.
Why is that so?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %h = ( "a" => "b" );
while ( my ($x, $y) = each %h ) {
    &do_something( \%h );
}

sub do_something(){
    my %tmp  = %{$_[0]};
}
```

Interestingly, this works:

```
while ( my ($x, $y) = each %h ) {
    &do_something( \%h );
}

sub do_something(){
}
```

While this does not:

```
while ( my ($x, $y) = each %h ) {
    &do_something( %h );
}

sub do_something(){
}
```

Comment: As a side note, [avoid using prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).  While they look like they're about controlling what a subroutine accepts, they really aren't.  They're about controlling the context of the arguments and have very limited use.  If you don't understand that, don't mess with them.  If you want subroutine arguments, look at [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/Method::Signatures).

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding prototypes. I was not aware that I did prototype my subroutine by writing `()`

Comment: Calling subroutines as `&foo` tells Perl to ignore prototypes, which is why you may have not noticed before.  There's no need for the `&`.

Comment: See [`Hash::SafeKeys`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Hash::SafeKeys), which I whipped up when [I had the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921221/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting the hash's content by evaluating it in list context uses the same iterator as `each`/`keys`/`values`, causing it to be reset.

Minimal demonstration:

```
>perl -E"%h=(a=>4); while (($k) = each(%h)) { say $k; keys %h }"
a
a
a
...

>perl -E"%h=(a=>4); while (($k) = each(%h)) { say $k; %t=%h }"
a
a
a
...
```

Since you only evaluate the hash in list context in the first and third snippets, the iterator is only reset in those two snippets.

---

PS — Why do you use an incorrect prototype (`()`) then tell Perl to ignore it (`&`)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Question: Do you say `each/keys/values` are all iterators? I would have guessed that `each` is an iterator, while `keys` and `values` are functions that return a list and do not reset any iterator other than `each`. Regarding the prototyping -- thanks for the hint, I was not aware that I did define prototypes.

Comment: How do you think `keys` gets all the keys? It has to iterate over the elements. It *uses* the same iterator has `each`.

Comment: @ikegami Klaus' reaction is perfectly correct.  One should be surprised that that `keys` resets the `each` iterator.  Even if they share the same iterator, `keys` could restore it.  It is non-obvious and a bad design.

Comment: @Schwern, Pretending his reaction is different than it was to offer criticism where it cannot help? Not cool. If what you say is possible, that's not a bad idea (although `keys` in void context must continue to reset the iterator), so why don't you file a bug report if not a patch.

Comment: @ikegami I read your response to Klaus with a heavily implied "how could it possibly be any other way" and "surely you could have figured it out".

Comment: @Schwern, Again, his question wasn't "why does `keys` and `each` use the same iterator?", it was "`keys` is an iterator?" So yes, I said "how could it possibly be any other way". You just have the wrong "it".

Comment: @ikegami I think I have the right "it".  There are many other ways to get the keys of a Perl hash (and to implement a hash).  A simple for loop over the internal C array holding the hash elements does the job and would probably be faster.  I don't know why they use an iterator, nor why there isn't an hv_keys function in the API to encapsulate the hash implementation.  To the original point, Klaus' intuition about how `keys` should work makes sense.  It's Perl's way of doing it that is off base.  So much of Perl is implemented in surprising ways to support obscure features.

Comment: @Schwerm, Re <I think I have the right "it"> Sorry, you're wrong. I'm 100% sure I was replying to "`keys` is an iterator?". Any insistance or thoughts to the opposite is not going to change that.