# Nested loop through a hash: infinite loop

Tags: perl

I'm experiencing a "strange" problem in Perl. I've defined a simple hash:

```
my %h = (
  one => 'this is my first value',
  two => 'and this is the second',
);
```

and I'm trying to iterate through it using `each` in a `while` loop:

```
while (my ($key, $val) = each %h) {
  print "$key, $val\n";  
}
```

pretty easy, and it works perfectly fine.

I then need to iterate through the same hash again, so I added a nested `while..each` as follows:

```
while (my ($key, $val) = each %h) {
    while (my ($key2, $val2) = each %h) {
      print "$key - $key2\n";  
    }
}
```

I'm expecting it to return just four lines, but I get an infinite loop instead:

```
one - two
one - two
one - two
one - two
....
```

What's happening there? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) commands on the same hash will share an iterator, so you will not get a nested iteration behavior.  (*read paragraph 3 of docs*)

Instead, the outer loop will start with 1st key/value pair, but then the inner loop will continue with the 2nd key until it reaches the end, at which point the shared iterator will be reset.  Then the outer loop will end up starting from the beginning again creating your infinite loop.

To accomplish nested iterators on the same hash, you'll need to use [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h = (
    one => 'this is my first value',
    two => 'and this is the second',
);

for my $key ( keys %h ) {
    for my $key2 ( keys %h ) {
        print "$key - $key2\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
one - one
one - two
two - one
two - two
```

Comment: great, I thought that using keys instead of each was just a matter of taste, now it works! thank you

Comment: NP. I would recommend to always use `keys`.  The first reason is because calls to `keys` are autonomous, unlike with `each`.  Secondly, it enables one to easily add code to specify a `sort` order, which would require two steps if one had used `each` initially.  Therefore, reduced chance of bugs and increased coding efficiency.

Comment: This works because a `for LIST` construction will read the entire list at the beginning of the loop. It's not actually a nested call to `keys`. If for whatever reason you actually do want to use nested calls to `each`, `keys`, or `values`, check out [`Hash::SafeKeys`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921221).