# Access a hash from debugger code without breaking the program's "each" iterator

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, hash, iterator, each

I have a problem with accessing hash elements without breaking Perl's `each` iterator.

According to [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html), using keys or values on a hash variable resets the hash's internal iterator, used by [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) and [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html). But it looks like simply copying the hash, as using something like

```
%other_hash = %hash
```

also resets the hash's iterator.

For example:

```
my %hash = ( 'A' .. 'D' );

my $n;

while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %hash ) {

    my %otherhash = %hash;

    print "$key=$value\n";

    last unless ++$n < 5;
}
```

#### output

```
C=D
C=D
C=D
C=D
C=D
```

I am writing a debugger which must provide variables' values to the IDE on each *step in* or *step over*. In case of hashes the debugger must be able to send the number of elements their values.

I've seen [*Can I copy a hash without resetting its "each" iterator?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921221/can-i-copy-a-hash-without-resetting-its-each-iterator).

Comment: Why don't you change your code example to what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: If you'll read question completely, you'll see what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you just capture `@keys = keys %hash; @values = values %hash;` before your loop and refer to those.

Comment: Your debugger should not break your code.  Perhaps use another debugging tool?

Comment: I'm debugger author. Not code author. And it should not, but it does. Guess that default console debugger do the same thing if you'll try to dump hash while inside the each loop.

Comment: Note: Question cross-posted to PerlMonks at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1166063

Comment: Did you try copying it into an array?  If having an array copy helps,I am not sure what exactly this with debugger entails.

Comment: As written in question - copying breaks it too. Read the question to understand how it related to the debugger

Comment: *"I'm debugger author. Not code author."* Then I think your question is misleading. You should open a new question, beginning with *I am writing a debugger, and ...*. Your *"In case of..."* paragraph is dense and over-informative, and many people will have overlooked it. I would have thought [`Hash::SafeKeys`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::SafeKeys) (as described in your final link) was exactly what you are looking for

Comment: I guess that question is ok and title is all about my question. It's not about "how iterate a hash and copy it", but it's "how to peek a hash without altering iterator"

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev  I did read your question. It doesn't even state what you want -- how to use a hash in the presence of a broken debugger, or how to fix the debugger itself? You cannot have a problem if you iterate over the _list_ (immutable) since it's generated upfront, see Borodin's answer. On the other hand, perhaps the tool is too zealous -- Why is it querying the whole hash inside the loop? The "_current lexical variables_" is one element _inside_ the loop block. That's just how hashes are, concurrent use of any of these functions with another won't work well.

Comment: @ I don't see how this "_question is easier_" -- once you "look" you can copy. If this is indeed about the debugger I think you'd have to get under the hood, or use a module that does so.

Comment: @zdim I guess this is problem of my bad English. Updated the title and question to be more specific. Also updated code

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev: You mustn't edit your question so that it makes nonsense of the answers and comments that have been offered. As I said in my comment above, *"You should open a new question"*. Many hundreds of people will arrive at this page because their problem is like what you describe, and it is those people that Stack Overflow is built for. I will roll back your question shortly

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev: Please don't use `peek`. It means something very specific in some circumstances, and very little in most. In my vocabulary it represents a [language function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEEK_and_POKE) that offers access to data by memory address using subterfuge. Since then we have invented virtual memory, and you should describe much better what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

One solution for this is [Hash::StoredIterator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash%3A%3AStoredIterator) module

Comment: You need to write something more to explain how this helps your situation

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Please note that the OP's question was meant to ask how to interrogate the values of variables within a running Perl program from within a debugger, presumably invoked using the `-d` switch

This solution won't help with that, but it does help with the apparent problem whereby `each` has a couple of issues and mustn't be used unless you are *certain* that your `while` loop will run to completion

*Reini Urban's* [*Do not use each*](http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2014/04/do-not-use-each.html)) addresses this well

---

Use a `for` loop over the `keys` list

`keys` in a list context returns a complete immutable list of the hash keys that won't be affected by anything

If you replace

```
while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each %hash ) {
    ...
}
```

with

```
for my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    my $value = $hash{$key};

    ...
}
```

then everything will work as you expect

Comment: If you'll read question and comments, you'll see that i'm not author of code, i'm author of debugger. So I can't modify code, i just need to made debugger not breaking the iterator

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev: That isn't a satisfactory answer. Your question has deceived many people in addition to myself

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev  But that is precisely the first problem with the question, that it asks about the code, not the debugger. I appreciate that you may have not meant that, but the question as originally posted states that. You say in this comment how _i just need to made debugger not breaking the iterator_ -- until a recent edit of the question this is the only such statement.  Please re-read your _original_ question.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've seen the question [*Can I copy a hash without resetting its "each" iterator?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921221/can-i-copy-a-hash-without-resetting-its-each-iterator), and I think there's nothing wrong with the answer there

I think [`Hash::SafeKeys`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::SafeKeys) is exactly what you want. It is written using Perl XS (C code) and should be plenty fast enough for a command-line program

Comment: Small addition about SafeKeys. It's slow and speed depends on the hash size; Tried to calculate keys number in 5k pairs hash 100k times: StoredIterator + default keys did it less than a second. SafeKeys took 46 seconds.